# javascript write to .txt file onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, flat-file

i have some swf apps that open in a lightbox when a link to an swf file is clicked on the page

it is purely standard link required to trigger the lightbox

```
<a href"http:// {url} /swf/ {file} .swf">Name</a>
```

i have been trying to implement a script to write a timestamp (date('U') in php coding, as that is the format i need the timestamp) and the "href" value of the link clicked to a txt file ... i have been using onClick="function()"

but i cannot seem to get it to work....

i am hoping to have lines written to the txt file like this

```
1328984654|http:// {url} /swf/ {file} .swf
1328984829|http:// {url} /swf/ {file2} .swf
```

i would presume the line breaks are implemented with \r\n

i dont necessarily need the file extention to be written, however i would presume it would be easier just to write the full link url....

the method i have been using was hidden form that submits onclick but its not very economical, as i need hidden iframe blah blah ...... too much work, when i think this could be implemented in one script....

i can easily change my existing link generating script, so that it can add

```
onClick="new_function()"
```

or any variation of this to be able to link it to the function....

i am not very experienced with javascript, and i know the click script will need to be client side :(

thanks in advance if anyone can help me, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript does not have access to the server file system and can not write anything to a file. However you can use javascript (read Ajax) to run a PHP file that writes whatever data you send it to a file.

For Ajax requests using jQuery is by far the easiest solution, as writing XMLHttpRequests in vanilla JS is a bit more complicated. In jQuery you would do something like:

HTML:

```
<a href"http:// {url} /swf/ {file} .swf" id="mylink">Name</a>
```

-

```
$("#mylink").click(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
       type: 'POST', 
       data: {swf : '1328984654|http: {url} /swf/ {file} .swf'}, 
       url: 'write_to_file.php',
       success: function(data) {
          alert('file saved');
       },
       error: function() {
          alert('error');
       }
    });
});
```

In PHP you'll get the data from the $_POST superglobal like so:

```
$data = $_POST['swf'];
```

Then use file_put_contents or one of the many other solutions for saving the data to your file, and since you've had this working with a form I'm not going to go into that part. You could also generate the timestamp in PHP and append that at the same time, no need to do that in JS. It is of course a bit more involved than this, for instance you should do the normal isset check on $_POST, and sanitize any data that comes from the clientside, but if you do a little reading and testing on your own you'll figure it out in no time, it's really not that hard, and just a few lines of code is enough to get a basic example of what you are trying to do up and running.

Comment: that is an excellent solution, thanks, but how would i use jquery to get the link url into the post variable? and how would i call the $.ajax command onclick? 

i have already implemented many flat file interactions with php on my site, wo the php side of things isnt a problem, thanks so much

Comment: In the example above I gave your '<a>' element an ID of 'mylink', and in the jQuery code you can see there is a '#mylink' click function, this actually runs the Ajax on every click on the <a> element. The data in the $_POST variable is from the data: attribute in the Ajax function, you'll see the same name there, 'swf', and the value that is stored in $_POST is whatever comes after the colon. You can go to jQuery's website 'jquery.com' to read more about any jQuery function, it does seem a little hard a first, but it does'nt really take that many hours to get the hang of the basic stuff.

Comment: ok i have found a tutorial on writing ajax requests, and i can send the data to the form with this 

xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");

..... but how can i get this request to send the variable (" http:// {url} /swf/ {file} .swf " .... i will be activating the request from an onclick event, but how to send the 'href' value from the link that called the onclick function?

Comment: ^^^^ there is multiple links on each page so i am confused,